# move data from database table to another table

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I created a VB.Net app with a SQLite DB and added some data
I can do all the CRUD functions NOW I came back to the app and added a new Table TxArchiveData with this code NOTE I omitted this part of the code in the new Table

```
NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

Code creating TxArchiveData TABLE below

```
        Private Sub btnNewTable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewTable.Click
        'create table TxArchiveDataTable String for cmd
        Dim create_table As String = String.Empty
        create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TxArchiveData(
                        TID INTEGER,
                        txSortDate TEXT,
                        txAmount TEXT,
                        txYear INTEGER,
                        txSearchMonth INTEGER)"

        Dim dbTable As String = "TxArchiveData"

        If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(dbTable) Then
            Try
                Using conn As New SQLiteConnection(connStr)
                    conn.Open()
                    Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(create_table, conn)
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End Using
                End Using
                tbMessage.Text = "TABLE Created Select BACK"
            Catch ex As Exception
                tbMessage.Text = "TxArchiveData Table FAILED"
            End Try
        End If
```

Here is the code to create the TxData TABLE NOTE shared naming

```
      Public Sub makeTxData()

        'create table TxDataTable String for cmd
        Dim create_table As String = String.Empty
        create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TxData(
                        TID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                        txSortDate TEXT,
                        txAmount TEXT,
                        txYear INTEGER,
                        txSearchMonth INTEGER)"

        Dim dbTable As String = "TxDataTable"

        If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(dbTable) Then
            Try
                Using conn As New SQLiteConnection(connStr)
                    conn.Open()
                    Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(create_table, conn)
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End Using
                End Using
                tbMessage.Text = "DB Created Select BACK"
            Catch ex As Exception
                tbMessage.Text = "TxData Table FAILED"
            End Try
        End If

    End Sub
```

On another form where I have not opened the SQLite DB I placed this code

```
     Private Sub btnMoveData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMoveData.Click
        Dim TxData As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim TxArchiveData As DataTable = New DataTable()
        For Each row As DataRow In TxData.Rows
            TxArchiveData.ImportRow(row)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Question is do I need to connect to the DB for the IMPORT ROW to work, and if so HOW?

I am also trying to only move data that matches the txYear column, adding this feature to the answer would be more than helpful**

I got this far still lost here is the code

```
       Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Dim TxData As New DataTable
        Dim TxArchiveData As New DataTable

        Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
            conn.Open()
            Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("", conn)

                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData"
                For Each dr As DataRow In TxData.Rows
                    TxArchiveData.ImportRow(dr)
                Next

            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, you need to connect to the database. Run a command to fill the source table into a _DataTable_ object and then you can move data around with other _in memory_ DataTable objects. Consider to search for some kind of tutorial on how the ADO.NET framework works.

Comment: @Steve Added Revised Code after searching and reading the dad Fill(dtd) not sure what I am missing If you have time to take a look

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Now you have a local variable named _dtb_ that has been filled with the data coming from the database table named _txData_ Of course, if the database table is empty so will be the local variable of type DataTable.

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. If there is new code relevant to the issue then add that to the question and explain that relevance.

Comment: @jmcilhinney OK I deleted the offending comment SO NOW lets work on solving the question I am reading as much as I can find about CLONE & COPY tables as well as IMPORTROW https://flylib.com/books/en/1.105.1/copying_rows_from_one_datatable_to_another.html

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things to address here.

Firstly:

> do I need to connect to the DB for the IMPORT ROW to work, and if so HOW?

No, of course you don't. `ImportRow` copies a `DataRow` from one `DataTable` to another. That's it, that's all. There's no direct connection between `DataTables` and databases. How you populate the source `DataTable` and what you do with the contents of the destination `DataTable` is irrelevant to the use of `ImportRow`. If the source data is coming from a database then obviously you need to connect to that database to retrieve that data, but that's unrelated.

Secondly, there's no need or point to using `ImportRow`. You only need one `DataTable`. You also only need one data adapter. The `SelectCommand` of a data adapter is executed when you call `Fill` and the `InsertCommand` can be executed when you call `Update`. There's nothing to say that they need to reference the same database table, or even the same database. You can `SELECT` data from one table and `INSERT` it in another, e.g.

```vb
Using connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here"),
      insertCommand As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table2 (Col1, Col2) VALUES (@Col1, @Col2)", connection),
      adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1", connection) With {.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False,
                                                                              .InsertCommand = insertCommand}
    With insertCommand.Parameters
        .Add("@Col1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Col1")
        .Add("@Col1", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Col2")
    End With

    connection.Open()

    Dim table As New DataTable

    adapter.Fill(table)
    adapter.Update(table)
End Using
```

An important point to note is the setting of the `AcceptChangesDuringFill` property. When you add a `DataRow` to a `DataTable`, its `RowState` is `Added` by default. When you call `Fill`, it adds the retrieved rows and then calls `AcceptChanges`, so that all the `RowStates` are set to `Unchanged`. By setting `AcceptChangesDuringFill` to `False`, you ensure that all rows remain `Added`, ready to be inserted.

Having said that, you don't even need to retrieve any data into your app to populate the new database table. You can use [`SELECT INTO`](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_select_into.asp) to create a new table, select records from an existing table and insert them into the new one. If the destination table already exists, you can insert into it and use a query as the source instead of a `VALUES` clause, e.g.

```sql
INSERT INTO Table2 (Col1, Col2)
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Table1
```

You can call `ExecuteNonQuery` on a command object to execute either of those options,

Comment: I have not tested your code yet but thank you It makes sense as I stumbled upon this AI generated code I made it work with one exception You can only transfer the data ONCE the second try gives a UNIQUE error Link to code if you want a look see https://codepal.ai/code-generator/query/A6Gi0C8e/vb-net-code-pull-data-from-one-table-to-another

Comment: @Vector, that means that you're adding the same data twice. Don't. That's a different issue though. If you are failing when trying to move the same data twice then that means that you've succeeded in moving it once, so the issue you actually asked about here is resolved. If you want to ask about another issue then you need to post a new question with ALL and ONLY the information relevant to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use ImportRow was the wrong tool for the job.
That said I am trying to Archive Data in another table so my DataGridView
only displays 2 years of data. Some what of a performance enhancement.
Here is the code that moves the data and a small routine that prevents the
user from moving the same data twice.

```
    Private Sub DataPull()

    ' Represents a utility function for writing data from one table to another in the same database.
    '
    ' PARAMETERS:
    I()
    If count > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("That Year " + tbYear.Text + " Has Been Archived", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If
    Dim sourceTable As String = "TxData"
    Dim destinationTable As String = "TxArchiveData"

    ' EXCEPTION:
    ' Throws SqlException if there is an error executing the SQL query.

    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
        conn.Open()
        ' Create a SQL command to select all data from the source table.
        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("", conn)
            cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM {sourceTable} WHERE txYear =" & tbYear.Text
            ' Execute the select command and retrieve the data.
            Using rdr As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                ' Create a SQL command to insert the data into the destination table.
                Using cmd2 As New SQLiteCommand("", conn)
                    cmd2.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO {destinationTable} VALUES (@Column1, @Column2, @Column3,@Column4,@Column5)"
                    ' Prepare the insert command parameters.
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Column1", DbType.Int64)
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Column2", DbType.String)
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Column3", DbType.String)
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Column4", DbType.Int64)
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Column5", DbType.Int64)

                    ' Loop through the data and insert it into the destination table.
                    While rdr.Read()
                        ' Set the parameter values.
                        cmd2.Parameters("@Column1").Value = rdr.GetInt64(0)
                        cmd2.Parameters("@Column2").Value = rdr.GetString(1)
                        cmd2.Parameters("@Column3").Value = rdr.GetString(2)
                        cmd2.Parameters("@Column4").Value = rdr.GetInt64(3)
                        cmd2.Parameters("@Column5").Value = rdr.GetInt64(4)

                        ' Execute the insert command.
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        count = count + 1
                        tbInfo.Text = count.ToString
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
            End Using
    End Using
End Sub
Private Sub I()
    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
        conn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("", conn)
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TxArchiveData WHERE txYear = " & tbYear.Text
            'Dim count As Integer Needs to be declard as toplevel variable
            'OR in a DataModule as gv_count it is used in DataPull() Sub
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", tbYear)
            count = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```